# Mockito: stubbing a method with a class argument, not behaving as expected

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have this class that just delegates an http call to a third party library:

```
public class HttpService
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    public <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> classOfT)
    {
        return gson.fromJson(json, classOfT);
    }
}
```

I am trying to stub that fromJson method, like so:

```
ExampleObject exampleObject = new ExampleObject("value1", "value2");

HttpService _testHttpService = Mockito.mock(HttpService.class);
Mockito.when(_testHttpService.fromJson(Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.eq(ExampleObject.class))).thenReturn(exampleObject);
```

Now when I call the fromJson method from the mocked HttpService object like so...

```
ExampleObject obj = _testhttpService.fromJson("blahblahblah" , ExampleObject.class);
```

...a value of null is assigned to obj.  Why is this?  I am trying to get the exampleObject returned.  I have tried several different Matcher methods to send in the class argument to the mocked constructor (i.e. in addition to Matchers.eq(), I have tried Matchers.same(), and a few others).  Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: What you have should work. Running it myself produces what you'd expect - `obj` and `exampleObject` reference the same `ExampleObject`. I had to correct the `_testhttpService` reference before it worked though.

Comment: Thanks for checking that out. This post is a simplified example of my actual code, but your results confirm that I should be able to make this work.  Looks like I have more investigation to do.  Thanks again!